# Using the elements of one Matrix to form a new Matrix with specified rules

Tags: matrix, rule, products

Given a matrix [a], how to get matrices [b] and [c] based on the following two rules?

1. rule [a]->[b]: Strike out corresponding term in [a] and take product
   of the remaining two terms in the same column.
2. rule [a]->[c]: Strike out the row and column containing the
   corresponding term in [a] and take sum of cross products in the 2×2
   matrix remaining.

**x,y,z can be replaced with 1,2,3; For example, $a_{xy},a_{yz}$ can be replaced with a12,a23; [a] can be replace with:**

```
a = {{a11, a12, a13}, {a21, a22, a23}, {a31, a32, a33}}
```

Thank you

Matrix [a]

[image]

Matrix [b]

[image]

Matrix [c]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
amat = Array[a, {3, 3}]

(* {{a[1, 1], a[1, 2], a[1, 3]}, 
    {a[2, 1], a[2, 2], a[2, 3]}, 
    {a[3, 1],  a[3, 2], a[3, 3]}} *)
```

For the first item, if you have no zero elements, then...

```
Map[Times @@ #/# &, Transpose@amat] // TeXForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a(2,1) a(3,1) & a(1,1) a(3,1) & a(1,1) a(2,1) \\
 a(2,2) a(3,2) & a(1,2) a(3,2) & a(1,2) a(2,2) \\
 a(2,3) a(3,3) & a(1,3) a(3,3) & a(1,3) a(2,3) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

If you have zero elements, then do this.

```
Transpose@Map[Table[Times @@ Delete[#, i], {i, 3}] &, Transpose@amat]
```

For the other, what you are asking for is similar to a minor. Use the generalized version of the function...first define a function that takes a 2x2 matrix and determines something similar to the cross product, but all positive terms.

```
f[m_] := m[[1, 1]] m[[2, 2]] + m[[1, 2]] m[[2, 1]]
```

Then call `Minors` passing `f[ ]` to be used on the submatrices instead of `Det`. Note we have to explicitly fix size of the submatrices. Also, see help on `Minors` to get the submatrices with the right rows and columns deleted.

```
Map[Reverse, Minors[amat, 2, f], {0, 1}]
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a(2,3) a(3,2)+a(2,2) a(3,3) & a(2,3) a(3,1)+a(2,1) a(3,3) & a(2,2) a(3,1)+a(2,1) a(3,2) \\
 a(1,3) a(3,2)+a(1,2) a(3,3) & a(1,3) a(3,1)+a(1,1) a(3,3) & a(1,2) a(3,1)+a(1,1) a(3,2) \\
 a(1,3) a(2,2)+a(1,2) a(2,3) & a(1,3) a(2,1)+a(1,1) a(2,3) & a(1,2) a(2,1)+a(1,1) a(2,2) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: I also thought first that it were about the minors; it is not. It think cross product means of a $2 times 2$ matrix in this context refers to $q_{11} q_{22} + q_{12} q_{21}$.

Comment: Ahh, yup. Updated the answer, can still use the `Minors` function to handle the bookkeeping.

Comment: Ah, `Minors` allows a third argument. That's great to know!

Comment: @MikeY, Henrik Schumacher. Thank you, it's a perfect solution.